# Ruby on Rails's best practice for main webpage's controller#action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If it is a website with a list of products, and then with links to each product,
is it good practice to make the homepage `products#index`? (products controller and index action).

Or is it a better practice to ignore `products#index`, and use `home#index`, and
then each product links to `products#show`?  Maybe both will work, but just a matter
of style, and possibly some pros and cons of using one vs the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on your application. If your application's main idea is products, then link it to `products#index`, if it's about cars, then route it to the cars controller. However if your homepage is going to be completely ambiguous, and just a landing page for example... make it `home#index`.

Comment: The base Home/WelcomeController is generally the first thing I get rid of in a new rails/mvc project.

Comment: I completely agree because most websites have a controller that is acceptable to be the front facing page of your site.